# Counting rows in a Derby Database (JavaDB) Netbeans

Tags: java, database, derby

Im doing a project at school with netbeans and ive made Diffrent users and etc for the game.
Can i make it so that Netbeans counts the rows in a specific table, then show it on my jLabel?
It so that on my login screen, The user can see how many Registered Users there are.

Thanks

Comment: _Can i make it so that Netbeans counts the rows in a specific table_ It's not Netbeans, it's java. Netbeans isn't a programming language, it's just the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

via jdbc issue that kind of query:

```
select count(*) from your_user_table
```